# Sort database results by the polymorphic relationship in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, relationship

I have an issue for sorting results by polymorphic relation in Laravel . 
Suppose we have two table like this :

```
users table : 
- integer id
- string  name 

meta table : 
- integer id
- string  key
- string  value 
- string  owner_type
- integer owner_id
```

Relation between users table and meta table is polymorphic relation.
So we have some users that each of them has some meta 
This is a hypothetical example of database records ( with meta )

```
id      1
name    "user1"
meta : 
   id           3
   key          "test"
   value        "3"
   owner_type   "App\\User"
   owner_id     1

   id           2
   key          "some other key"
   value        "some other value"
   owner_type   "App\\User"
   owner_id     1

id      2
name    "user2"
meta :
   id           3
   key          "test"
   value        "2"
   owner_type   "App\\User"
   owner_id     2
```

Now I want sort users results by meta value column where key is test .
something like this :

```
$results = User::with(['meta' => function($q){
     $q->where('key' , 'test');
}])->orderBy('meta.value')->get();
```

But of course the code above does not work

What's your solution ?
If we want get users from database and sort results by value of a meta  witch has a special key what we should do ?

note : I want sort the data before getting results

Comment: What have you tryed at this point? Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about a join?

```
$results = User::join('meta', 'users.id', '=', 'meta.owner_id')
                   ->where('meta.key','=','test')
                   ->orderBy('meta.value')
                   ->select('users.id', 'users.name')
                   ->get();
```

Comment: I had tried join before. It was just a little mistake that I noticed now . thanks anyway